# Calculus: Finding the minimum: Why is this the answer?

Tags: calculus

Why is does the minimum of the function $$f(x,y)=-{1\over x\left[1-\left({x\over y}\right)^{p-1}\right]}$$
for some $p\in (0,1)$ and $x,y>0$, also $f$ can only take non-negative values (though this is probably irrelevant here), occur at $$\left({x\over y}\right)=\left({1\over p}\right)^{1\over p-1}$$?
I don't know how to extremize $f$ since there are $2$ variables and they don't always occur in the form $\left({x\over y}\right)$.

Comment: $[...]$ is the floor function?

Comment: @BabakS.: It's just a square bracket...

Comment: You should differentiate the function with respect to $x$ and set the derivative equal to $0$. Do the same with the variable $y$. See what you'll get.

Comment: @Matt: OOh , thanks!